# How can I union all rows of two different tables using MySQL 8.0.17 version?

Tags: mysql

These are two tables of my MySQL database 8.0.17

On these tables the corresponding column for each tables is the column `tUnity`

```
-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for t_release
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `t_release`;
CREATE TABLE `t_release`  (
  `tID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `tUnity` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tMonthYear` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tHHrelease` datetime(0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tHHapproved` datetime(0) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`tID`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

-- ----------------------------
-- Records of t_release
-- ----------------------------
INSERT INTO `t_release` VALUES (1, 'D41', '1-2021', '2021-02-26 16:22:19', NULL);


-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for t_unities
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `t_unities`;
CREATE TABLE `t_unities`  (
  `tID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `tUnity` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`tID`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

-- ----------------------------
-- Records of t_unities
-- ----------------------------
INSERT INTO `t_unities` VALUES (1, 'D40');
INSERT INTO `t_unities` VALUES (2, 'D41');
INSERT INTO `t_unities` VALUES (3, 'D42');
INSERT INTO `t_unities` VALUES (4, 'D43');
INSERT INTO `t_unities` VALUES (5, 'D44');
INSERT INTO `t_unities` VALUES (6, 'D45');
INSERT INTO `t_unities` VALUES (7, 'D46');
INSERT INTO `t_unities` VALUES (8, 'D47');
INSERT INTO `t_unities` VALUES (9, 'D48');
INSERT INTO `t_unities` VALUES (10, 'D49');
```

I need union these tables for this return

```
+--------+------------+---------------------+-------------+--------+
| qUnity | tMonthYear | tHHrelease          | tHHapproved | tUnity |
+--------+------------+---------------------+-------------+--------+
| D40    |            |                     | NULL        | D40    |
| D41    | 1-2021     | 2021-02-26 16:22:19 | NULL        | D41    |
| D42    |            |                     | NULL        | D42    |
| D43    |            |                     | NULL        | D43    |
| D44    |            |                     | NULL        | D43    |
| D45    |            |                     | NULL        | D45    |
| D46    |            |                     | NULL        | D46    |
| D47    |            |                     | NULL        | D47    |
| D48    |            |                     | NULL        | D48    |
| D49    |            |                     | NULL        | D49    |
+--------+------------+---------------------+-------------+--------+
10 rows in set (0.03 sec)
```

And I have tried this SQL query

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    q.tUnity AS qUnity,
    t.tMonthYear,
    t.tHHrelease,
    t.tHHapproved,
    t.tUnity AS tUnity
FROM
    t_release t
    LEFT JOIN t_unities q ON LEFT ( t.tUnity, 2 ) = LEFT ( q.tUnity, 2 ) 
WHERE
    LEFT ( t.tUnity, 2 ) = LEFT ( 'd400', 2 ) 
    AND tMonthYear = '1-2021';
```

But the return from this SQL query is

```
+--------+------------+---------------------+-------------+--------+
| qUnity | tMonthYear | tHHrelease          | tHHapproved | tUnity |
+--------+------------+---------------------+-------------+--------+
| D40    | 1-2021     | 2021-02-26 16:22:19 | NULL        | D41    |
| D41    | 1-2021     | 2021-02-26 16:22:19 | NULL        | D41    |
| D42    | 1-2021     | 2021-02-26 16:22:19 | NULL        | D41    |
| D43    | 1-2021     | 2021-02-26 16:22:19 | NULL        | D41    |
| D44    | 1-2021     | 2021-02-26 16:22:19 | NULL        | D41    |
| D45    | 1-2021     | 2021-02-26 16:22:19 | NULL        | D41    |
| D46    | 1-2021     | 2021-02-26 16:22:19 | NULL        | D41    |
| D47    | 1-2021     | 2021-02-26 16:22:19 | NULL        | D41    |
| D48    | 1-2021     | 2021-02-26 16:22:19 | NULL        | D41    |
| D49    | 1-2021     | 2021-02-26 16:22:19 | NULL        | D41    |
+--------+------------+---------------------+-------------+--------+
10 rows in set (0.03 sec)
```

**Update**

```
    SELECT
        q.tUnity AS qUnity,
        t.tMonthYear,
        t.tHHrelease,
        t.tHHapproved,
        t.tUnity AS tUnity 
    FROM
        t_unities q
        LEFT OUTER JOIN t_release t ON t.tUnity=q.tUnity
    WHERE
        LEFT ( t.tUnity, 2 ) = LEFT ( 'd400', 2 ) 
        AND tMonthYear = '1-2021';
    
    +--------+------------+---------------------+-------------+--------+
    | qUnity | tMonthYear | tHHrelease          | tHHapproved | tUnity |
    +--------+------------+---------------------+-------------+--------+
    | D41    | 1-2021     | 2021-02-26 16:22:19 | NULL        | D41    |
    +--------+------------+---------------------+-------------+--------+
    1 row in set (0.03 sec)
```

**Solved**

```
SELECT
    q.tUnity AS qUnity,
    t.tMonthYear,
    t.tHHrelease,
    t.tHHapproved,
    t.tUnity AS tUnity 
FROM
    t_unities q
    LEFT OUTER JOIN t_release t ON t.tUnity = q.tUnity 
    AND LEFT ( t.tUnity, 2 ) = LEFT ( 'd400', 2 ) 
    AND tMonthYear = '1-2021';

+--------+------------+---------------------+-------------+--------+
| qUnity | tMonthYear | tHHrelease          | tHHapproved | tUnity |
+--------+------------+---------------------+-------------+--------+
| D41    | 1-2021     | 2021-02-26 16:22:19 | NULL        | D41    |
| D40    | NULL       | NULL                | NULL        | NULL   |
| D42    | NULL       | NULL                | NULL        | NULL   |
| D43    | NULL       | NULL                | NULL        | NULL   |
| D44    | NULL       | NULL                | NULL        | NULL   |
| D45    | NULL       | NULL                | NULL        | NULL   |
| D46    | NULL       | NULL                | NULL        | NULL   |
| D47    | NULL       | NULL                | NULL        | NULL   |
| D48    | NULL       | NULL                | NULL        | NULL   |
| D49    | NULL       | NULL                | NULL        | NULL   |
+--------+------------+---------------------+-------------+--------+
10 rows in set (0.03 sec)
```

Comment: Why `LEFT ( t.tUnity, 2 ) = LEFT ( q.tUnity, 2 )` and not `t.tUnity = q.tUnity`?

Comment: @forpas thanks for reply. Pls see **Update** on the question

Comment: Did you try a LEFT join of t_release to t_unities since you want all the rows of t_release?

Comment: @forpas yes the output bot change, only one row...

Comment: The column tUnity in your expected results contains values other than `'D41'` which is the only value in t_unities. Shouldn't there be nulls in all other rows except `'D41'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do a `LEFT` join of `t_unities` to `t_release` and set all the conditions in the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT 
    q.tUnity AS qUnity,
    t.tMonthYear,
    t.tHHrelease,
    t.tHHapproved,
    -- q.tUnity AS tUnity
FROM t_unities q LEFT JOIN t_release t
ON t.tUnity =  q.tUnity
AND LEFT(t.tUnity, 2) = LEFT('D400', 2) 
AND t.tMonthYear = '1-2021';
```

or:

```
SELECT 
    q.tUnity AS qUnity,
    t.tMonthYear,
    t.tHHrelease,
    t.tHHapproved,
    -- q.tUnity AS tUnity
FROM t_unities q LEFT JOIN t_release t
ON t.tUnity =  q.tUnity
AND t.tMonthYear = '1-2021'
WHERE LEFT(q.tUnity, 2) = LEFT('D400', 2)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=03a5a5bfb1f109d66bddf1b498846fdf).
Results:

| qUnity | tMonthYear | tHHrelease | tHHapproved |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| D40 | null | null | null |
| D41 | 1-2021 | 2021-02-26 16:22:19 | null |
| D42 | null | null | null |
| D43 | null | null | null |
| D44 | null | null | null |
| D45 | null | null | null |
| D46 | null | null | null |
| D47 | null | null | null |
| D48 | null | null | null |
| D49 | null | null | null |